# How to fight in close quarters without alerting the guards?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

When I fight in close quarters, right before I land a blow, soldiers will always turn towards me. Since one bonus is to not to enter reflex mode, this means I will lose this bonus.

I always approach my target from a dead angle and crouching so I do not understand why this happens.

Comment: What metal gear solid 5 are you asking about? There are 2

Comment: Better to tag it with what everyone else is using for TPP questions...

Comment: Its not about what others use it for its about author intent.

Comment: thanks for tagging, the tags are inconsistents between all versions of MGS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Turn off Reflex Mode
2. At default crouching speed with the first suit, your footsteps can still be heard. You must walk (CTRL) while to sneak up to an enemy.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to CQC a guard without alerting him, is by grabbing him. Simply keep the CQC button pressed when you see the hand symbol on screen.

Once you've grabbed him, you can either strangle him<sup>**1**</sup> (non-lethal, silent, slow), knock him out<sup>**2**</sup> (non-lethal, loud, fast), or kill him<sup>**3**</sup> (lethal, silent, fast).

---

<sup>**1**</sup>: release the CQC button just long enough so you can press it again, then keep it pressed until the guard loses consciousness. According to @Lucas Leblanc, you can choke faster if you mash the CQC button instead of simply holding it.
<sup>**2**</sup>: Double tap the CQC button while pressing the left analog stick (or the arrow buttons) in any direction.
<sup>**3**</sup>: Press the contextual action button.

Comment: You should mention that you can strangle guards faster by mashing the CQC button repeatedly after beginning the choke. Just holding it causes the choke out time to be painfully long. The mashing is a wink-and-nod to the "classic trilogy" before the franchise's controls were revamped in MGS4, in which choke-outs had to be performed by mashing the CQC button repeatedly after grabbing (hold circle, then mash circle).

Comment: @LucasLeblanc. Thanks, added it to my answer. I guess I got too used to MGS4's choking system, which required to apply more pressure to the CQC button. One of the reasons I liked MGS 4 so much. I miss the lack of pressure sensitive buttons on the PS4...

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is simply moving too fast.

If you're trying to sneak up on them from behind you can only move just that little bit quicker than a patrolling enemy's walking pace once you get up close until, as mugen2099 mentioned you get the sneaking suit which will quieten your footsteps.

The other alternative is to get into cover round a corner from them and wait for them to patrol around to you or draw them in by knocking, tossing a magazine or using DD's bark command though the bark will draw everyone in about a 30 meter radius so check your markers.

Answer (score 0):

To CQC without alerting the guard, you either will:

A:
Have to CQC in Reflex mode and act fast.

or

B:
Get a new camo/suit. In the description of some camos/suits, you will see "noise reduction soles". When it rains, it also reduces your sound when moving. The Sneaking Suit is a really good choice for a great Jack-of-all-Trade suit, and it offer some bullet protection, allowing you to live longer.

Comment: Option A doesn't work here, he asked specifically what to do to NOT get into Reflex mode, since you get extra points for that. Also, "getting a new suit to reduce noise" is not really a good answer either. The issue at hand is not him being spotted all the time. He's facing an issue where he constantly gets a slow-mo upon doing CQC moves and he wishes to know if there are any moves that will not go into slow-mo.

Comment: Also, is he asking for phantom pain as you assume, or is he infact asking aboit ground zeroes?

Comment: Don't they use the same engine?

Comment: They do use the same engine, so the answer would work for both games.